# Filtering all dictionary key values based on single key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Say, if we have a dictionary like below:

```py
{'time' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'x_coordinates': [3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 8, 9],
'y_coordinates': [3, 5, 8, 1, 7, 3, 7, 2, 5, 2]
}
```

And one like:

```py
{'time' : [2, 6, 8, 10]}
```

I want to filter out all the key values belonging to the first dict by the key values belonging to the second dict. That is my desired output would be:

```py
{'time': [2, 6, 8, 10], 
'x_coordinates': [1, 8, 4, 9],
'y_coordinates': [5, 3, 2, 2]
}
```

How can I do this in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I think the question really is *"How do I retrieve corresponding list elements"*, based on what your expected output is

Comment: If you know how to identify the element matches between the time list, then it's a matter of identifying the corresponding values in the other lists. Do you have any code you've tried?

Comment: Is list corresponding to `'time'` sorted always?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this myself. I can show what I have tried but someone already answered.

Comment: @Ch3steR yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
a={'time' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'x_coordinates': [3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 8, 9],
'y_coordinates': [3, 5, 8, 1, 7, 3, 7, 2, 5, 2]
}
search={'time' : [2, 6, 8, 10]}
idx=[a['time'].index(i) for i in search['time']]
#[1, 5, 7, 9]
final_dict={key:[a[key][i] for i in idx] for key in a.keys()}
```

---

```
{'time': [2, 6, 8, 10],
 'x_coordinates': [1, 8, 4, 9],
 'y_coordinates': [5, 3, 2, 2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are looking for corresponding list elements based on the list provided for `time`. This can be accomplished with `zip`, and to construct your dictionary, you could leverage a `defaultdict`

```py
from collections import defaultdict


d = {'time' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'x_coordinates': [3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 8, 9],
'y_coordinates': [3, 5, 8, 1, 7, 3, 7, 2, 5, 2]
}

# sets provide faster lookup times than lists
vals = set([2, 6, 8, 10])

new_values = defaultdict(list)


for time, x, y in zip(d['time'], d['x_coordinates'], d['y_coordinates']):
    if time in vals:
        # you only have to do a single membership test, then you 
        # simply append the desired values
        new_values['time'].append(time)
        new_values['x_coordinates'].append(x)
        new_values['y_coordinates'].append(y)


defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'time': [2, 6, 8, 10], 'x_coordinates': [1, 8, 4, 9], 'y_coordinates': [5, 3, 2, 2]})
```

The benefit here is that you only iterate once over all of the values